# Calculate All Possible Combinations to 100%

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, percentages, chemistry

I have a list of chemicals with percentages composing a certain alloy. I am trying to find a way to see all possible combinations summing to 100%, but am a bit stuck with the maths.

For this example, let's consider only a few:

Titanium: 30% to 98%

Iron: 0% to 15%

Niobium: 0% to 40%

How could I see all the possible combinations of these three elements that sum to 100%?

I started down the path by simply finding the product by increments of 1%. But this gives values both less than and greater than 100%.

Thanks,
Kris

Comment: Welcome to Mathematice SE! Do you have any attempts / ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: For a way to visualise the "solution space" for three elements, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot.

Comment: Alex, I've started to create a matrix of possible combinations. My actual data includes 18 elements, each with varying ranges, such that the matrix is very large (1.29 E20). My thought, currently, is simply to lay this out and then find only the instances where the sum of the elements is 100%. This seems brute-force, in terms of methodology, so thought it was worth asking if there is a better way.

Comment: pigeonhole principle will help a bit.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee - can you expand on that a bit? I read through the wiki for this principle, and see how it's related, but not sure how to apply.

Answer (score 0):

$$15+40=55; 
100-55=45$$

These facts, show that no mixture of these 3 in these ranges hits 100% before titanium is 45%. Any higher, and we have metals sharing percentages without bringing the other two down.

$$100-98=2$$

Shows that even with 98% titanium, you'll need 2% of the other metals. This upper and lower bounds them. It can be thought of in terms of pigeonhole principle.

Similarly anything below 70% Titanium will have to have at least 16% Niobium (rounding up) as that's forced even if you allow an equal as possible mixture of the other two metals. etc.